# Port forwarding not working on ZTE router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding

I am using a ZTE wi-fi router. My laptop's private IP is 192.168.1.2 where Apache server is running on port 8080. I added the NAT rule to forward http traffic to my laptop.

Protocol - all
Starting port - 8080
End port - 8080
Local IP - 193.168.1.2

However when I browse [public_ip]:8080 shows nothing. when I browse [public_ip]:80 I can log into the router.

How to be sure that ISP is blocking or router is not forwarding?

I tried disabling dhcp, still the same result.
 I port scanned using nmap, fallowing is the result.

PORT   STATE SERVICE
21/tcp open  ftp
23/tcp open  telnet
80/tcp open  http

[image: Port forwarding settings]

Comment: Did you restart your router once you added the rule?

Comment: Yes, same result after restarting

Comment: Have you tried the same rule, but on port 80?

Comment: @MatthewWilliams As I stated in the issue description, public_ip:80 logs me to the router after asking the credentials even when I am having the rule.

Comment: Yes, but does the same result happen when you state a rule for port 80?

Comment: @Matthew yes the http://public_ip:80 log me into the router when I have the rule for 80.

Comment: However port scanning with nmap shows
PORT   STATE SERVICE
21/tcp open  ftp
23/tcp open  telnet
80/tcp open  http

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 5128, section 2.10](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5128#section-2.10) reads:

> Hairpinning is defined in [BEH-UDP] as follows:
>
> If two hosts (called X1 and X2) are behind the same NAT and
> exchanging traffic, the NAT may allocate an address on the
> outside of the NAT for X2, called X2':x2'.  If X1 sends traffic
> to X2':x2', it goes to the NAT, which must relay the traffic
> from X1 to X2.  This is referred to as hairpinning.
>
> **Not all currently deployed NATs support hairpinning.**

Your router simply doesn't support hairpinning. Try connecting to the server from outside the NAT.

Comment: I had the same problem and when accessing my local IP address from outside the NAT, the port forwarding works as expected.